# How do you split an array of numbers and push positive numbers to an array and negative numbers to another?

Tags: javascript

How do you split an array of numbers and push positive numbers to an array and negative numbers to another?
var myarr = [1,2,3,-1,5,-3];

Answer (score 3):

You could take the singn and push to the according property of an object, where the value is an array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -3],
    positive = [],
    negative = [],
    hash = { 1: positive, '-1': negative };
    
array.forEach(a => hash[Math.sign(a)].push(a));

console.log(positive);
console.log(negative);
```

For treating zero as positive number:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -3, 0],
    positive = [],
    negative = [],
    hash = { true: positive, false: negative };
    
array.forEach(a => hash[a >= 0].push(a));

console.log(positive);
console.log(negative);
```

The classic way with filtering

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -3, 0],
    negative = [],
    positive = array.filter(a => a >= 0 || (negative.push(a), false));

console.log(positive);
console.log(negative);
```

Comment: what if there is a 0 in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myarr = [ 1,2,3,-1.5,-3 ];

var positive = [];
var negative = [];

for( key in myarr ) {

    var item = myarr[ key ];

    if( item < 0 ) {

        negative.push( item );

    }
    else {

        positive.push( item );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**check each array value with less than 0 or not if less than 0 than its negative otherwise it positive**

try this code

```js
var myarr = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -3];
var pos = [];
var neg = [];
for (i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
  if (myarr[i] < 0) {
    neg.push(myarr[i]);
  } else {
    pos.push(myarr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(neg);
console.log(pos);
```